# Issue tabbing between fields in Tiddlywiki

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> are great for getting in and out of fields without taking your hands off the keyboard.

In my Firefox 9.0 installation I installed and then disabled [Tab in Textarea 0.10.2 (tabinta)](http://code.google.com/p/tabinta/) and now when I try to tab in and out of a textarea on the page using <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> it gives me a tab instead of the expected movement in and out of the textarea.  Is there some way I can get this functionality back to normal?

Comment: So, do you want an alternative method of tabbing/shift-tabbing? Or do you want to fix your problem?

Comment: I think I have a hunch now the problem may be the web application I'm using...cause it doesn't do it on other websites... :-p

Comment: AH! Yup that was it!  I'm using Tiddlywiki and there's an option In the AdvancedOptions tiddler which reads 'Use the tab key to insert tab characters instead of moving between fields'.  So that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using Tiddlywiki and there's an option In the AdvancedOptions tiddler which reads `'Use the tab key to insert tab characters instead of moving between fields'`. So that was it!

Comment: Must be a new feature they added or something.  I'll stick to using tabinta thanks.